# Java application using Sqlite Database without supplying an existing database with the installer package

Tags: java, sqlite

I have developed a demo application in java.It has a simple log-in screen that has username and password fields.Now,i am using sqilte for the purpose.I am able to log in to by connecting to the predefined database.But i want to run the application in a different machine with successful log in.For this purpose I want to create a database in the different machine automatically from the application if it does not exist.For that I want to package the application in to an executable installer and install in a different machine and run it.Sqlite being an embedded database what is the exact solution to it?

Comment: I just created that application experimentally...just to check whether it's possible or not.

Comment: You can reword this question to ask how you include a SQLite database as part of your Java application, i.e. how to package it and where the file should be located (etc).

Comment: Where is code ?

Answer (score 1):

Just include a default/sample SQLite database file in your installer package or application. SQLite isn't magic, it's just a file on the filesystem.

From: [Creating Database in JDBC Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950482/creating-database-in-jdbc-sqlite)

The SQLite JDBC string you're using contains the filename of the file you should copy:

```
jdbc:sqlite:filename.db
```

The file `filename.db` will be in your application's working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Creating Database in JDBC Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950482/creating-database-in-jdbc-sqlite).

Then you can use create table if not exist to create your tables and relations.

Comment: how to achieve that(create table if does not exist) ?...could u elaborate that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098008/sqlite-create-table-if-doesnt-exist