# null pointer exception while creating sqlite database android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

here is the code.

```
public class DatabaseManager extends android.app.Activity
{
    public SQLiteDatabase mydatabase ;
    private static final Object MODE_PRIVATE = null;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Fests";

    // this function is called first.
    public  void createDatabase()
    {
        try{

    mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("fests",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
    System.out.println("no probs with open function.");
    mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fests (FestId VARCHAR,Festname VARCHAR);");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("creating db","exception caught."+e);
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception in the first line itself i.e. openOrCreateDatabase function,  unable to figure out why. 
I am new to android programming.Please help me.

Comment: please share the logcat output with us

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14950482/66519

Comment: DatabaseManager should extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, change what you class extends.

You also don't need your variable `mydatabase`. There is already one in the class called `database`. It will handle the creation of it for you, if you supply the name & version.

E.g.

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Name.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

/**
 * this gets called automatically on opening the database
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

// if the database does not exist this method is called to create it
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    for (String CREATE_TABLE : CREATE_TABLES)
    {
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }
}

// when the version changes this method updates the version number and
// creates a log entry
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(SQLiteHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
            + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    for (String TABLE: TABLES)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `public class DatabaseManager extends android.app.Activity` which is wrong change it to `public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper`